# How to install Webcenter Portal Mail Services

Tags: portal, webcenter

I want to activate mail service on webcenter portal. But mail service does not appear on the services and providers page. How do I make it appear the mail service?

Sory for my poor language.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several prerequisites.

Oracle provides a configuration roadmap for configuring the Mail Service:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/webcenter.1111/e27738/wcadm_mail.htm#WCADM9793

I can tell from your screenshot you are not on the most recent 11.1.1.8 version yet, here is the same documentation, but for 11.1.1.6:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/webcenter.1111/e12405/wcadm_mail.htm#WCADM9793